# Update Html.RenderPartialAsync() from ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a partial view in a view, which i load in the following way from my parent view:

```
<div id="listOfEntities">
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_PartialView", Model.GetEntities());}
</div>
```

As you can see, the partial view use the model in the parent view to fetch a list of entities that are to be used in the partial view.

The partial view displays a list, that I want to update regularly, when the user interacts with the parent view. For example, I have the following ajax post method that ideally should update my partial view, upon a successful ServiceResult, i.e.:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/DeleteEntity',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { "SomeObject": object },
    success: function (data) {
    //DO SOMETHING HERE TO UPDATE THE PARTIAL VIEW
    },
    error: function (data) {
    //Error from serviceResult - do not update view
    }
});
```

Since I'm fairly inexperienced with Ajax methods, I have no idea if I actually do this the right way, hence why I ask this question.

Will I even be able to update the partial view, since it uses the model of the parent view? Would I have to create a separate controller that returns the partial view, accompanied by the model?

If I'm completely off track here, I would very much like to know how I should correctly achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are the right path. 
Just need to add someone method which will return GetEntities().

```
public ActionResult _PartialView()
{
     return PartialView(Model.GetEntities());
}
```

And then put a load function in ajax success parameters.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/DeleteEntity',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { "SomeObject": object },
    success: function (data) {
       $('#listOfEntities').load('/<controller>/_PartialView');
    },
    error: function (data) {
       console.log('something went wrong');
    }
});
```